# Minimizing the expression $(1+1/x)(1+m/y)$ over positive reals such that $mx+y=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers such that $mx+y=1$. Find the positive $m$ such that the minimum of:

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)\left( 1 + \frac{m}{y} \right).$$

is $81$.

I have tried expanding, using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but nothing helped.

Comment: I would like to somebody could use the CS-inequality here. I don't see vectors and I don't see an inner product.

Comment: Why did you edit your post to be completely meaningless when it seems you had a valid question to begin with?

Comment: In case you are still not getting it: your question is going to stay on this site, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Yes :( [char limit]

Comment: While the initial question was sensible and inspired a good answer, the OP now seems determined to use it as a platform for vandalism. So I vote to close.

Comment: @mathelte696 You can delete it, you know.

Comment: @columbus8myhw No, a question with an upvoted answer cannot be deleted by the OP. (Also, in this case the OP is an unregistered user, so they can't delete anyway).

Comment: @Semiclassical That is a wrong move in such a case. Closing prevents answers, it does nothing about edits. The better move is to flag for mod's attention (which I did a while ago), pointing out repeated vandalism of one's post. Mods have tools which we don't have: locking and suspension.

Comment: Also, for everyone: when you see a comment with vulgar words like those that used to be above, *flag the comment as rude/offensive*. The system checks the presence of certain words: one flag deletes the comment in such a case. (cc: @JackD'Aurizio )

Comment: Wow amazing, sorry for this.
My brother was using my computer.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x=\frac{1}{m}(1-y)$, we have:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{y}\right)=\left(1+\frac{m}{1-y}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{y}\right),\tag{1}$$
and since $f(x)=1+\frac{m}{x}$ is a log-convex function, the minimum of the RHS of $(1)$ over $(0,1)$ occurs when $y=\frac{1}{2}$, and the value of such a minimum is just $(1+2m)^2$. The answer is so $m=4$.

---

In order to avoid log-convexity, we can just write down the RHS of $(1)$ in the following form:
$$ g(y) = 1+\frac{m+m^2}{y(1-y)}$$
and notice that $y(1-y)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ due to the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), from which:
$$ f(y) \geq 1+4m+4m^2 = (2m+1)^2 $$
with equality occurring only when $y=(1-y)$, i.e. $y=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very slick solution ;) But I doubt that log-convex functions are covered in precalc. Taking the derivative of the expression on the right-hand side and setting it equal to zero, however, also gives $y=1/2$. This is possibly more pedagogical.

Comment: @BoSchmidt: you're right, I am updating my answer with your alternative approach avoiding log-convexity.